# How to Convert my compiler from python2 to python3

Tags: python, version

I am trying to convert from. python2 to python3. Using "python --version", I was able to see that my PATH variable points to python2 and not python3 which I also have available on my machine. This become obvious whenever I type in alias python=python3, the result comes up as python 3.9.2 which is the latest version of python I installed recently.

The problem now, and where I have spent hours tryin to figure things out, is how to tell the interpreter to default on the updated version of python (python3) when I am using the IDE to run a program.

Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: What IDE are you using? You should be able to specify which interpreter you want to use there.

Comment: I am using PyCharm

Answer (score 1):

You should be using virtual environments ;)

```sh
pip install virtualenv
```

then make a virtual environment with:

```py
python3 -m venv .env
```

You could replace `.env` with whatever name you like. For more information on this, I'd suggest you take a look at the [docs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Sure, thanks. After hours of trying to figure things out the issue was resolved.